# Map and forward traffic from multiple PCs to multiple router with iptables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, forwarding

Is it possible to configure a linux server with iptables to do this?

```
PC (192.168.1.11) ===> (192.168.1.1) Linux Server (192.168.0.100) ===> Router1 (192.168.0.1)
PC (192.168.1.12) ===> (192.168.1.1) Linux Server (192.168.0.100) ===> Router1 (192.168.0.1)
PC (192.168.1.13) ===> (192.168.1.1) Linux Server (192.168.0.100) ===> Router1 (192.168.0.1)
...
PC (192.168.1.21) ===> (192.168.1.1) Linux Server (192.168.0.100) ===> Router2 (192.168.0.2)
PC (192.168.1.22) ===> (192.168.1.1) Linux Server (192.168.0.100) ===> Router2 (192.168.0.2)
PC (192.168.1.23) ===> (192.168.1.1) Linux Server (192.168.0.100) ===> Router2 (192.168.0.2)
...
PC (192.168.1.31) ===> (192.168.1.1) Linux Server (192.168.0.100) ===> Router3 (192.168.0.3)
PC (192.168.1.32) ===> (192.168.1.1) Linux Server (192.168.0.100) ===> Router3 (192.168.0.3)
PC (192.168.1.33) ===> (192.168.1.1) Linux Server (192.168.0.100) ===> Router3 (192.168.0.3)
...
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: With iptables no, since it's not a facility intended for routing. With (policy) routing yes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you please tell me about that in detail? How can I do it on ubuntu? Does it require 3rd-party software or else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*iptables* is not a tool for routing. Although it can sometimes be used to complement routing configuration by marking packets, this is not even needed here.

What is required is [policy-based routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing): using something else than just the destination address to choose a route: the source address.

Assuming or stating that:

- the Linux server will be called *server*
- All 9 PCs, *server* and the 3 routers are already configured according to OP's schematic

  - in particular the PCs don't need any special setting. They just need to have *server* as default gateway.
- All addresses in OP's schematic use a /24 [CIDR/netmask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#IPv4_CIDR_blocks).
- *server* uses:

  - *eth0* with address 192.168.1.1/24
  - *eth1* with address 192.168.0.100/24
  - *server* might or might not have a default gateway, it doesn't matter.
    Policy routing will use its own separate settings for forwarded traffic so doesn't rely on the main routing table's default gateway if any.

If not already done the 3 routers will need additional routes to reach 192.168.1.0/24 with *server* as gateway. Same would be needed on systems to reach in LAN 192.168.0.0/24. If they were running Linux this would be done on the 3 routers or any other system with:

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.0.100
```

**EDIT**: as [asked later](https://serverfault.com/questions/1103370/map-and-forward-traffic-from-multiple-pcs-to-multiple-router-with-iptables/1103562#comment1440539_1103562), if one is not allowed to reconfigure other systems in 192.168.0.0/24 LAN, *server* can use NAT on server to hide the existence of 192.168.1.0/24 to those systems, including the 3 routers. As this is done outside of the routing phase, this will be independent of the rest of the routing configuration below.

So instead of above done on routers (or any other system), one can use an *iptables* [`MASQUERADE`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#MASQUERADE) target on *server*:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Now on *server*, 3 alternate group of rules are created to reach three additional routing tables: one per selected router, with this router as default gateway. It's correct that there can be only one default gateway, but it's one per routing table.

As the PC's IP addresses aren't ordered in blocks, 3x3 rules are used (with correctly aligned IP blocks, 3 rules would be enough with adequate CIDR/netmasks).

Described in [`ip rule(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-rule.8#DESCRIPTION):

> In some circumstances we want to route packets differently depending
> not only on destination addresses, but also on other packet fields:
> source address, IP protocol, transport protocol ports or even packet
> payload. This task is called 'policy routing'.
>
> [...]
>
> Each policy routing rule consists of a selector and an action
> predicate.

In this case, the selector will select the PC's source addresses and the action will be to lookup the additional routing tables thus overriding the usual lookup for the *main* table to choose a dedicated gateway.

Routing rules (which could be simplified up to only 3 rules if PC's IP addresses were aligned in adequate blocks):

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.11 lookup 10
ip rule add from 192.168.1.12 lookup 10
ip rule add from 192.168.1.13 lookup 10

ip rule add from 192.168.1.21 lookup 20
ip rule add from 192.168.1.22 lookup 20
ip rule add from 192.168.1.23 lookup 20

ip rule add from 192.168.1.31 lookup 30
ip rule add from 192.168.1.32 lookup 30
ip rule add from 192.168.1.33 lookup 30
```

Described in [`ip route(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-route.8#DESCRIPTION):

> **Route tables**: Linux-2.x can pack routes into several routing tables identified by a number in the range from 1 to 2^32-1 or by name
> from the file /etc/iproute2/rt_tables By default all normal routes are
> inserted into the main table (ID 254) and the kernel only uses this
> table when calculating routes. [...]

Populate additional routing tables with arbitrary values 10 20 and 30. Each routing table will handle one partial view of the routing adequate to the problem to solve. Here it's about choosing a different gateway.

```
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth1 table 10
ip route add default via 192.168.0.2 dev eth1 table 20
ip route add default via 192.168.0.3 dev eth1 table 30
```

Should the PCs need to access other systems in 192.168.0.0/24 these LAN routes should be added (to avoid partial hairpin through the routers which is never a good idea):

```
ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1 table 10
ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1 table 20
ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1 table 30
```

The result cat be checked on *server* with `ip route get`:

```
root@server:~# ip route get from 192.168.1.11 iif eth0 to 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 from 192.168.1.11 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth1 table 10 
    cache iif eth0 
root@server:~# ip route get from 192.168.1.21 iif eth0 to 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 from 192.168.1.21 via 192.168.0.2 dev eth1 table 20 
    cache iif eth0 
root@server:~# ip route get from 192.168.1.31 iif eth0 to 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 from 192.168.1.31 via 192.168.0.3 dev eth1 table 30 
    cache iif eth0
```

Other systems in 192.168.1.0/24 LAN follow the *main* routing table without policy-based routing. For example if *server* has no default route in *main* table but only its two LAN routes, then nothing else will be routed beyond 192.168.0.0/24 LAN:

```
root@server:~# ip route get from 192.168.1.41 iif eth0 to 8.8.8.8
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
```

---

Notes

The 3 routers could be for example Internet gateways doing NAT and reaching Internet
in a cheap setup using each a single different public IP address (possibly using a different ISP) making the 3 groups of PCs seen on Internet with 3 different public IP addresses.

The setup above will have to be integrated with the tool configuring network on *server*. There are many such tools depending on the distribution, such as *ifupdown*, *NetworkManager*, *systemd-networkd*, *netplan* and probably many others, each with their specific configuration method. It's also certainly possible to use a script with given commands above instead.

Comment: Thanks for your great and detailed help! This surely works like a charm.
One quick question, is there any way to set up this without router config? (`ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.0.100`)

Comment: Another question, can I implement this with pcap instead?

Comment: (lib)pcap is for capturing packets. This doesn't make sense to talk about pcap. As for avoiding router config, This can be avoided by using SNAT (MASQUERADE) on server instead.

Comment: answer changed (see **EDIT**).